# Linear Regression Contain NaN Values

Tags: python, linear-regression

I had an array contain price of a car by month like this

```
| Date | Price($) |
| -------- | --------------  |
| 2019-09-01| NaN            |
| 2019-09-02| NaN            |
| 2019-09-03| 250            |
| 2019-09-04| 200            |
| 2019-09-05| 300            |
```

The question here is I wanted to make a linear regression for predicting price of this car in next month (e.x: price of car in 2019-10-01 is ...$). But when I try to fit input to linear regression model I got this bug: *ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').*
Here the code :

```
data = mydata #load my data
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue, one simpler way to do it, is to dropna() at the dataframe level itself.

```
data= data.dropna(axis= 0, how='any')
```

Then, all rows containing the na data will be dropped and the regression can work smoothly.

Comment: This line of code help me reducing noise causing by mean value in linear regression. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

LinearRegression will not be able to train on the points with missing data.

As a workaround, you can fill these missing data points using `SimpleImputer`.

```
import numpy as np
data = mydata #load my data
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column
# imputing Y data points to fill missing values
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(Y)
Y_imputed = imputer.transform(Y)
# using imputed data for training
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y_imputed)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions
```

Here, NaN in `Y` will be filled with imputation.

**Note:** If you can't fill these NaN values using imputation, then you should try to avoid using these data points for training.

**Update:** `Impute` function is deprecated in `scikit-learn` since 0.23+

Comment: it's would be so nice if you explain more carefully with my code

Comment: i tried, but still got this error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: I have updated code with `np.nan`. Ideally it should work and your NaN values should be filled correctly using `mean` of the data.